# What is meant by Synchronized Hashtables?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

What does it really mean when we say that Hashtables are synchronized?
Moreover, what is the difference between Synchronized HashMaps and Hashtables and which one should we use?

Comment: did you read the javadoc on each class and the oracle java concurrency tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old Java Hashtable class is threadsafe -- it's protected so multiple threads can't damage it by trying to use it simultaneously. HashMap does not have that protection, because in most cases the right thing to protect is not just the hashtable access but the logic surrounding that access ... and if the user is going to implement their own synchronization, doing it again in the hashmap costs performance for no functional gain.

A good tutorial on multithreaded coding in Java will tell you more about the meaning and use of `synchronized` code.